# Webpack, typescript and angularjs: issue while creating new project

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, ts-loader

I am new to webpack and typings, i am trying to setup new project.

I have globally installed the webpack.

Issues are

1. Even it is not allowing me to put the code of entrypoint.ts in a module like

   module taxCalculator{
   [.....entrypoint.ts code.......]
   }
2. webpack build works fine when i avoid point 1 but i am not able to use the testClass in entrypoint.ts while creating  mainPageController. when i load the application get following error in console:

   taxCalculator.bundle.js:13307 ReferenceError: taxCalculator is not defined
3. In my entrypoint.ts vs 2013 shows the red error line below the 'require' text.

I have already referred a lot on internet but could not find anything and wasted 4-5 hours of mine, can someone please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Following are my files for reference.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "taxcalculator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "To Calculate Tax",
  "scripts": {
    "build": ""
  },
  "author": "temp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "1.3.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.0",
    "typings": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "registry:dt/angular#1.5.0+20170111164943"
  }
}
```

entrypoint.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="TestClass.ts"/>

    var angular = require('angular');
    var app = angular.module('taxCalculatorApp', []);

    app.controller("mainPageController", ["$scope", function(scope) {
        scope.testString = "My String Value";

        scope.myObj = new taxCalculator.TestClass("Constructor string");
    }])
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
    <title>Tax Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="taxCalculatorApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainPageController">
        <div>{{testString}}</div>
        <div>{{myObj.myString}}</div>
    </div>
    Loading.....!!
</div>
    <script src="../dist/taxCalculator.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

testclass.ts

```
module taxCalculator {
    export class TestClass {
        constructor(public myString) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the compilerOptions section of your tsConfig file, add the following:

```
"moduleResolution" : "node", // or "classic"
"module" : "amd",
```

The `moduleResolution` section determines how the tsc compiler looks for modules. A full description can be found on the [typescript docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

The `module` section describes how each of your modules will be written out. By default this will be `CommonJS`, which is not what you want. It should probably be `amd`, which is a front-end friendly module system.

It's a good idea to take a deeper [look at all the compiler options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and see if any more are relevant for your project. In general, starting off new projects with *strict null checks* and *no implicit any* will help you in the long run.

Comment: thank you for the answer but did not work even after adding these two in tsconfig.json, still facing same problems at same places.

Comment: Andrew did you get a chance to look again, i am still facing the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I have not.